# Taylor's series and ln

Tags: taylor-expansion

Can someone explain to me how to find the $\lim \limits_{x \to 3} \frac{\ln|4-x|}{x-3}$ using taylor's series.

Can someone explain the proof of $\ln|4-x|$ to power series please

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was not able to find the pattern, sorry i just found out it was (x-3) ^n *(n-1)!/n!

Comment: @Blah You may want to see my answer for the proof of $\ln |4-x|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have with $h=x-3$

$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\ln\vert 4-x\vert}{x-3}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln\vert1-h\vert}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-h+o(h)}{h}=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

For the proof of $\ln|4-x|$, write

$$\frac{1}{4-x}=\frac{1/4}{1-(x/4)}=\frac{1}{4}\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^n$$

since $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ when $|x|<1$.

Now, try integrating both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \ln |4-x|.$ The limit is

$$\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{f(x) - f(3)}{x-3} = f'(3)$$

by the definition of the derivative.